# Plotly in Python: show mean and variance of selected data

Tags: python, plotly, histogram

I am generating histograms using `go.Histogram` as described [here](https://plotly.com/python/histograms/). I am getting what is expected: [image]

What I want to do is to show some statistics of the selected data, as shown in the next image (the white box I added manually in Paint): [image]

I have tried [this](https://plotly.com/python/v3/selection-events/) and within the function `selection_fn` I placed the `add_annotation` described [here](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/). However, it does nothing. No errors too.

How can I do this?

Edit: I am using this code taken from [this link](https://plotly.com/python/histograms/)

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randn(500)
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Histogram(x=x)])
fig.show()
```

with obviously another data set.

Comment: Please includea fully runnable code snippet in your question.

Comment: I have no code basically, that is what I am asking for. I mean, I want to add such a functionality to any histogram made with plotly.

Comment: You're saying in your question that you're `getting what is expected`. How?